# Can SQL injection be performed on a broken query?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Could an SQL injection be performed to find data about a MySQL database where the table in the original query doesn't exist?

For example, consider this query in PHP:

`mysqli_multi_query("INSERT INTO users (id, email_address) VALUES (NULL, '$email');");`

If the table `users` didn't exist, could an injection still be performed? The main issue I can see is the entire query operation will throw an error if I try to inject something like the following:

`'); SHOW TABLES; --`

This is more for my education than anything in practical use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

This won't do SQL injection even if the table does exist. `mysql_query()` doesn't perform multiple queries, so injecting a `;` to start a second query will not work. Most other MySQL APIs are similar -- you have to use something like `mysqli_multi_query()` to be able to perform multiple queries in a single call.

But if the first query fails for some reason, none of the following queries will be executed. So in your example, if there's no `user` table, you can't inject into it.

This is not very interesting, though. SQL-injection is generally done to queries that are working properly except for not properly protecting against injection. So there's no likely situation where you'd inject into a query that's accessing a nonexistent table.

Comment: Ahh, meant to make it `mysql_multi_query`. Good catch. I've used PDO/prepared statements for a long time so the basic php MySQL functions aren't my area of expertise anymore. Thanks for your reply! Cheers.

Comment: So you're postulating hacking a site that uses multi-query to query a nonexistent table? You're better off playing the lottery. :)